# Authentication Middleware for routes not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Vue, Vuex with Quasar (Quasar might or might not be irrelevant here)

This is my first Application and so I am not sure if I am doing things correctly or not

Below is the code snippet for my routes

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'


Vue.use(VueRouter)

/*
 * If not building with SSR mode, you can
 * directly export the Router instantiation
 */

const routes = [

  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MyLayout.vue'),
    beforeEnter: ifAuthenticated ,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('./../container/Index.vue') }
    ]
  }
]

const ifNotAuthenticated = (to, from, next) => {
  console.log("here")
  if (!store.getters.isAuthenticated)  return next()
  else  next('/')
}

const ifAuthenticated = (to, from, next) => {
  if (store.getters.isAuthenticated) return next()
  else  next('/login')
}


export default function (store) {
  const Router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history', 
    routes,

    // Leave these as is and change from quasar.conf.js instead!
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> vueRouterMode
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> publicPath
    mode: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE,
    base: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE
  })

      return Router
}
```

Here notice this line of code

```
const ifNotAuthenticated = (to, from, next) => {
  console.log("here")
  if (!store.getters.isAuthenticated)  return next()
  else  next('/')
}
```

With this I was expecting to do client side authentication and based on my understanding/reading about client Authentication

I thought this would be called  when I did something like this

```
beforeEnter: ifAuthenticated ,
```

But unfortunately that function isn't being called (since it isn't console logging anything).

Any idea of what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You're not calling `ifNotAuthenticated` anywhere in your code, so you won't see the console log message.

It's probably easier and better to use global `beforeEach` guard for checking authentication. Here's a very simple example code how you can do it using `meta` data in your routes config.

I added comments in the code to explain things.

I recommend you to read [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) in Vue Router documentation. 
Also a nice [article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/vue-authentication-and-route-handling-using-vue-router) explaining things more in detail.

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "Dashboard",
    component: () => import("path/to/Dashboard.vue"),
    // Add a metadata like this to your private routes
    // Tip: If you have a lot of private routes, you can add
    // meta: { public: true } to public routes and make
    // all other routes private by default.
    // In this case you need to change the logic in beforeEach
    // below.
    meta: { requiresAuth: true },
  },
];

export default function(store) {
  const Router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes,
    // Other stuff...
  });

  Router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    // See if any of the matched routes has meta "requiresAuth"
    if (to.matched.some(route => route.meta.requiresAuth)) {
      // Yes this route requires authentication. See if the user is authenticated.
      if (store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
        // User is authenticated, we allow access.
        next();
      } else {
        // User is not authenticated. We can redirect her to
        // our login page. Or wherever we want.
        next("/login");
      }
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });

  return Router;
}
```